Footnotes let paragraphs flow into each other, no paragraph separation with empty lines after footnote
I'm asking this question because footnotes at the end of a paragraph make the subsequent paragraph merge with the current one.
The separating space (or indention) to the following paragraph vanishes and the text continues to flow on the same line.
Is there a way to avoid this? tex4ht does not output the expected "<p>" tag in the generated XHTML.
Minimal example
A minimal LaTeX example with two footnotes at the end of two paragraphs:
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Biography}

\section{Russell as a 4-year-old}

His paternal grandfather, Lord John Russell, later 1st Earl Russell (1792–1878),
had twice been prime minister in the 1840s and 1860s. A member of Parliament since
the early 1810s, he met with Napoleon Bonaparte in Elba.\footnote{Problems with paragraphs after this footnote.}

Lady Amberley was the daughter of Lord and Lady Stanley 
of Alderley. Russell often feared the ridicule of his
maternal grandmother.

%\subsection{Childhood and adolescence}

Russell had two siblings: brother Frank (seven years older),
and sister Rachel (four years
older).\footnote{Problems with paragraphs after this footnote.}

The Countess was from a Scottish Presbyterian family and
petitioned the Court of Chancery to set aside a provision
in Amberley's will requiring the children to be raised.

Russell's adolescence was lonely and he contemplated suicide.

During these formative years, he also discovered the works of
Percy Bysshe Shelley. Russell wrote: "I spent all my spare time
reading him, and learning him by heart, knowing no one to whom
I could speak of what I thought or felt, I used to reflect
how..."

He travelled to the continent in 1890 with an American friend ...
\end{document}

Compiled with:
tex4ebook -a info -x -f epub3 -t test.tex

Problematic result: Paragraphs after footnotes not separated, text flow continues on same line:

Desired result: Paragraphs separated after footnotes


Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thank you, @Mensch! :-)

Try this version of tex4ebook-epub3.4ht:
%\typeout{!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!epub3!!!!!!!!!!!!}
\Configure{NcxDoctype}{}
\Configure{VERSION}{}

% we must remove attributes from opf namespace
\def\print:opf:scheme#1{}
\Configure{OpfScheme}{}

\Configure{OpfMetadata}{\HCode{<meta property="dcterms:modified">}\:iso:date\HCode{</meta>}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Configure toc nav %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Configure{tableofcontents}{
  \a:NavMap
  \resettoclevels{part,appendix,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
  \navsection{part}{part,appendix,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
  \navsection{appendix}{appendix,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
  \navsection{chapter}{appendix,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
  \navsection{section}{section,subsection,subsubsection}
  \navsection{subsection}{subsection,subsubsection}
  \navsection{subsubsection}{subsubsection}
   %\HtmlParOff
    \Configure{toTocLink}{}{}   
}{\b:NavMap}{}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcount\:toccount
\Configure{NavMap}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\boolfalse{tocnoempty}\global\advance\:toccount by1\HCode{<nav id="toc\the\:toccount" class="toc" \ifnum\:toccount<2 epub:type="toc"\fi>\Hnewline<ol>}%
\opf:registerfilename{\FileName}
\ifnum\:toccount<2 \opf:add:property{nav}\fi
}{\usetoclevels{part,appendix,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}%
    \ifbool{tocnoempty}{}{\HCode{<li><a href="\jobname.\:html">Document</a></li>}}
    \HCode{</ol></nav>}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\Configure{NavSection}{%
    \booltrue{tocnoempty}
    \HCode{<li>}}{\HCode{<ol>\Hnewline}}{\ }{\Tg</ol>\Tg</li>}
% Disable numbering of the TOC by the reading system, numbers are added by tex4ht
\Css{nav.toc ol{list-style: none;}}
%%%% End toc nav configuration
\def\CoverMetadata#1{%
\special{t4ht+@File: #1}%
\Configure{OpfManifest}{\HCode{<item id="cover-image" properties="cover-image" href="#1" media-type="\a:CoverMimeType" />}}%
}
%\Configure{CoverImage}{%
%  \HPage{}%
%  \Configure{OpfManifest}{\HCode{<item id="cover-image" properties="cover-image" href="}\CoverImageName\HCode{" media-type="\a:CoverMimeType" />}}%
  %\box0=\hbox\bgroup
%  \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP%
%  \HCode{<section epub:type="cover">\Hnewline}}
%}
%  {%\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP%
   %\HCode{</section>\Hnewline}%
   %\EndHPage{}
   %\egroup
%}
%\:CheckOption{mathml}
%\if:Option
\apptocmd{\a:DviMath}{\opf:add:property{mathml}}{}{}%
%\fi
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{xmlns}{}{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}
\Configure{xmlns}{epub}{http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops}
%\Configure{xmlns}{m}{http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML}
%\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html\t4ht:xmlns lang=\"}\GetLanguage\HCode{">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html\t4ht:xmlns lang="}\NoFonts\GetLanguage\EndNoFonts
\HCode{">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta charset="UTF-8" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht
        (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/\string~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="\expandafter\csname aa:CssFile\endcsname" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{EpubVersion}{3.0}
\Configure{OpfItemProperties}{properties="}{"}

% Structural elements

\:CheckOption{fn-in}
\if:Option
\else
% Foootnote configuration for epub3
% Footnotes are printed directly after the paragraph they appeared in
% footnotebox - configure box in which footnotes are printed
% default configuration doesn't work in ibooks, don't know why
\NewConfigure{footnotebox}{2}
\Configure{footnotebox}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\HCode{<section epub:type="footnotes" class="footnotes">\Hnewline}}%
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\HCode{\Hnewline</section>\Hnewline}}%
\newbox\footnotebox%
% We must create new link command, so footnote mark can link to footnote text
\LinkCommand\fnlink{aside,href,id,class="footnote" epub:type="footnote"}
\Configure{footnotemark}{\NoFonts\Link[ epub:type="noteref"]{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum}{}}{\EndLink\EndNoFonts}%
\Configure{footnotetext}{\SaveEndP\global\setbox\footnotebox=\vtop\bgroup\NoFonts%
    \ifvoid\footnotebox\else\unvbox\footnotebox\fi%
    \bgroup%
  \IgnorePar%
    \fnlink{}{fn\FNnum x\minipageNum}\par\AnchorLabel%
}{\EndNoFonts}
{%
    \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{\Hnewline}%
    \Endfnlink\egroup\egroup\RecallEndP}%

\def\printfn{%
    \ifvoid\footnotebox\else%
    \a:footnotebox%
    \box\footnotebox%
    \b:footnotebox%
    \fi%
}

% configure HtmlPar to print footnotebox.
\Configure{HtmlPar}
{\EndP\printfn\HCode{<p class="noindent">}}
{\EndP\printfn\HCode{<p class="indent">}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p>\Hnewline}}

\Css{.footnote{font-size:small;}}
\Css{.footnotes hr{width:30\%;margin:0 auto 0 0;}}
\Css{p + section.footnotes{margin-bottom: 1rem;}}
\fi

It produces a following result:


Thank you very much, @michal.h21 -- I'm amazed as this even works with my original example, even though your solution is much beyond my understanding. I'm much obliged for your fast answer.
Does it make sense to use this version of tex4ebook-epub3.4ht as the standard, or is there a good reason why better not to do so?
Thank you very much again!

I will update tex4ebook sources with this version, but it may take some time before I post the updated version to CTAN, so you can use this version in the meantime. The code is a bit messy, because it uses some workarounds and even I don't understand why some things don't work as expected :/

Hm, that's not optimal, but still great work, @michal.h21 ! Please let me know if and how I can help you in your work for tex4ht and tex4ebook.

@Timfunke alternatively, you can try the "fn-in" option. It will place all footnotes at the end of the current chapter.

Not really, @michal.h21 , as this again would make the paragraphs merge. So your original solution is the (only) one that works :-)

@Timfunke OK, at least that works :)
